# Does a barbarian's unarmored defense count when flat footed?

Tags: dnd-5e, barbarian, defense

A flat footed character loses their dexterity bonus to their AC.
Is a Barbarian's Unarmored Defense still considered if caught flat footed?
Perhaps just the Con bonus?
Help?

Comment: Have you read through the 5e player's handbook? Where are you getting the idea that Flat Footed is a part of 5e? Is it from an online resource?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no concept of "flat-footed" in 5th Edition.

Most situations that would have given flat-footed (blinded, paralyzed, petrified, prone, restrained, stunned, and unconscious) in 3.5 instead give the attacker advantage on the attack roll.

Flanking and facing are available as variant rules in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, and they, too, grant advantage on attack rolls.

Advantage is a simpler way to grant the bonus; it's fewer stats for each player to keep track off.  It does reduce the difference between the various armor types, and if your table wants to houserule flat-foot AC into 5e, I would recommend that you remove the advantage from those status effects to compensate.

Comment: We were just talking about this in our session the other day -- it didn't make sense to us that someone who is paralyzed keeps their dex bonus to AC.  I think if someone is paralyzed, they should lose their dex bonus to AC AND you should get advantage against them.

Comment: @PurpleVermont Does not the advantage mechanically simulate the paralysis? If I'm paralyzed, sure I have a hard time dodging your blow, that's why you get to roll twice. It's two different mechanics to simulate the same thing, and 5e just lumps all of those cases into one mechanic.

Comment: @sillyputty I'd get advantage even if you were prone but still dodging.  It seems like I should get more if you're completely unable to move.

Comment: @PurpleVermont Hm. Solid point. I'd debate further, but that's what chat is for.

Comment: how do we take it to chat?  Sometimes it offers a link if you've posted too many comments, but I don't know how to do it otherwise

Comment: There was a post a while back about exceptional advantage or exceptional disadvantage. I think the result was roll 3d20 and take the highest/lowest. Might give you the feeling of what you want without the extra math.